# Haxe as syntax, how to use AS3 as

Tags: haxe

I have this line in AS3 and did not find a proper cast to use.

```
var ok:LoginOk = msg as LoginOk;
```

Can someone tell me how to do that in Haxe, `LoginOk` extends `msg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [unsafe cast](https://haxe.org/manual/expression-cast-unsafe.html):

```
var ok:LoginOk = cast msg;
```